# How Tables are getting updated in bigquery

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

May I know any method or way to check how the table is getting updated in bigquery ?

Scenario -
Data coming from google firebase dumped into table X in bigquery. Once the table X got completed it migrate the entire data to table Y. After creation of table Y it shouldn't be updated but it
is getting updated.

I couldn't find any document or way to find out how my table is getting updated.

Please let me know if you require any more info.

Thanks

Comment: Why table Y shouldn't be updated? Do you want to enforce different permission on the table X and the table Y to prevent  firebase to write in Y?

Comment: It doesn't suppose to be updated, we are not dumping any more data. We need to understand from where the data is coming or why the table is still  getting modified.

Comment: In Cloud Logging, you have the audit log that show you the operation on the table. Like this, you will be able to see the identity of the actor, the timestamp and the operation performed on this table.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info! 
Could you also please elaborate the steps to check logs as I couldn't find audit logs.

Comment: Can anyone help here! couldn't find audit logs.

Comment: Please follow the [Official Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit#viewing_audit_logs) where it shows you different options to view your audit logs.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Cloud Logging, filter on the resource BigQuery and you will be able to view something like this:

[image]

The type of this log is Audit log (3rd line). You can also see WHO has performed the action, here, it's me, as PrincipalEmail (line 7).

Then, you have details on the operation. Here a select, but you can see if it's an insert, update, or stuff like this. The query capacity of Cloud Logging is very powerful!!